# For each row, find all rows with same values in column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to achieve the following using pandas in python:
For each row, I want to get the rows (e.g. the indices) of all other rows where in some column they have the same value, e.g.

```
    B   Result
0   1   [1, 2]
1   1   [0, 2]
2   1   [0, 1]
3   5   [5]
4   0   []
5   5   [4]
```

So my dataframe originally consists only of the column B, and I want to fillout result. Row 0 gets [1, 2], as the rows 1 and 2 have the same value in column B as row 0, and so on.

A possibility I think would be to do a groupby and then do some kind of merge, however, I am wondering if there is no better / efficient way? this seems so easy and I would expect a one-liner function.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two steps

```
df['result']=df.B.map(df.groupby('B').B.apply(lambda x : [x.index.values][0]))
df['result']=df.reset_index().apply(lambda x : list(set(x['result'])-set([x['index']])),axis=1)
df
Out[1569]: 
   B  result
0  1  [1, 2]
1  1  [0, 2]
2  1  [0, 1]
3  5     [5]
4  0      []
5  5     [3]
```

Comment: what would I do if I want to group by multple columns? somehow I run into problems ...

Comment: @Oliver yw happy coding

Comment: i think im not really understanding what the map does here, in combination with the groupby

Comment: @Oliver df.groupby(['c1','c2'])

Comment: @Oliver in here, you can think about map as merge

Comment: simply df = pd.DataFrame({'B' :[ 1, 1, 1], 'C' : [2, 4, 5]})

Comment: @Oliver groupby two ?

Comment: yeah, group by B and C

Comment: @Oliver using df['A']=df.B.astype(str)+df.C.astype(str), then we have all group key in one column A

Comment: great. thanks a lot. although to be fair its maybe not the nicest solution .. ?

Comment: @Oliver maybe not , but I would like to do the data perpetration outside the groupby, cause, groupby is time cost function

Comment: sorry, somehow I still run into problems with that. How would I fill the column result with multiple values, e.g. different, multiple columns instead of just the index?

Comment: i.e. the list being inserted into column results, which is now a list of indices, should be a list [[x1.Column1, x1.Column2], [x2.Column1, x2.Column2], ...]